# "Selection does not contain a main type" error when running JavaFX in eclipse.

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am extremely new to java and I am trying to run this segment of code in eclipse. I understand that this means that I don't have a main method in my code, but the FX project is supposed to work without the main method. I right clicked on the src file and tried to run it as a java application from there, but it just gives me that error. Here is the code that I am trying to run. As far as I know, there is nothing wrong with the code itself, so is there some sort of setting that I have to configure? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.collections.*;


public class HelloWorldMain extends Application{
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();

    // put all controls on 'pane'
    Label lblHello = new Label("Hello");
    pane.getChildren().add(lblHello);

    Button btnHello = new Button("Hello World");
    pane.getChildren().add(btnHello);

    TextField txtHello = new TextField("Hello");
    pane.getChildren().add(txtHello);

    PasswordField pass = new PasswordField();
    pane.getChildren().add(pass);

    CheckBox cbHello = new CheckBox("Hello");
    pane.getChildren().add(cbHello);

    RadioButton rbMale= new RadioButton("Male");
    RadioButton rbFemale = new RadioButton("Female");
        pane.getChildren().add(rbMale);
        pane.getChildren().add(rbFemale);

    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    rbMale.setToggleGroup(group);
    rbFemale.setToggleGroup(group);

    ChoiceBox cbColors = new ChoiceBox();
    cbColors.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Red", "Green", "Blue"));

    pane.getChildren().add(cbColors);


    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

to your class and run.
You're welcome.

> but the FX project is supposed to work without the main method

What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Well now I feel embarrassed. Thank you sir

Comment: The code that I used was from a tutorial and I saw it running without the main method.